# Bad link crashes Python IRC bot

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, bots, irc

My bot uses Beautiful soup to parse HTML, and also prints out the web page title of a link said in IRC. This all works except for one thing: If someone gives a dead/fake link, the bot crashes.

The link grabber triggers when "http" is found, so for example if someone just said "http", it crashes because there's no response. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's the part of the code that grabs the link and get's the web page title and posts it:

```
msg_split = msg.split(' ')
for item in msg_split:
    if re.search('^http.*', item, re.I):
        link = item
        if item.find(','):
            link = link.replace(',', ' ')
            soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(link))
            link_title = soup.title.string
            ircSend('PRIVMSG ' + args[2] + ' ' + link_title)
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the line(s) that cause the bot to crash?

Comment: Adding the entire HTML parser

Comment: Indents seem to be incorrect (do not reflect proper logicnyou probably use). Please correct them. Also take a look at what str.find() returns: if it does not find anything, it returns -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `soup = ...` through `ircSend(...` lines in a try/except statement.

```
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(link))
    link_title = soup.title.string
    ircSend('PRIVMSG ' + args[2] + ' ' + link_title)
except IOError:
    pass
```

Comment: Are you using urllib specifically or another URL library via something like `import urllib2 as urllib`? IOError is the only error urllib should return, but you can try changing the 'except' line to just `except:` by itself.

Comment: Does the bot give you any information about the crash, like a traceback printed to the console?

Comment: Alright, now it doesn't crash, but now it doesn't send the title in the IRC.

Comment: Did the bot give you a traceback when it crashed? What did you change that made it not crash?

Comment: It didn't give any traceback. The error that I fixed is that there was some conflicting variables if there was no link

Comment: Oh, I see what was going wrong. That was partially my fault; I've updated my code snippet above, can you check if that works?

Comment: Can you post whatever code you're currently attempting to run? The syntax error could indicate a couple of different things.

Comment: I got it, there was a spacing issue. Everything is now working as intended. Thank you for the help!